# Install rpy2 on custom R location (Linux)

Tags: python, r, linux, rpy2, pythonanywhere

I am trying to get rpy2 to install from source on Linux running on pythonanywhere with the follow:

```
tar -xzf rpy2-2.9.1.tar.gz
cd rpy2-2.9.1
python3.6 setup.py build install
```

The problem is I don't have admin rights and the default version of R is too old (R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)) for what I need. I therefore have installed a local version of R by following the these steps:

1. downloaded the tar.gz of the development version of R from : ftp://ftp.stat.math.ethz.ch/Software/R/
2. uncompress it to /home/{username}/R
3. changed into the uncompressed directory /home/{username}/R/R-devel
4. run "./configure"
5. run "make"

I can now start R by executing /home/{username}/R/R-devel/bin/R and my R library is located /home/{username}/R/R-devel/library.

I am not sure how to set these paths so that python will know where my R installation is when I run 'python3.6 setup.py build install' in the rpy2 package directory.

The rpy2 documentation says that you can pass the following parameter into build: --r-home, --r-home-lib, and --r-home-modules. I have yet been successful at doing this. As far as I can tell, these parameters are deprecated.

Any help getting this to work is appreicated. Thanks!

Here is some information about the Linux distribution on Pythonanywhere.

> lsb_release --all
>       No LSB modules are available.
>       Distributor ID: Ubuntu
>       Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
>       Release:        14.04
>       Codename:       trusty

Comment: What happens if you just use the `--prefix` flag when building R, setting it to `/home/yourpythonanywhereusername/.local`, and then do a `make install` (without `sudo`) at the end?   In theory, that would put a full R install in your `.local` directory, which you could then build against when building rpy.  You could then use `pip install --local .` instead of the `python3.6 setup.py build install` command for the last step.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I wasn't able to get it to work.

Comment: What happened?  Did you get any errors?